# Draw nodes in a graph clustered based on color and space out nodes Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I had the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60061960/draw-nodes-in-a-graph-clustered-based-on-color). The solution works, however, I cannot seem to space out the nodes and make them appear in a circular format like the solution shows. The nodes of the same color are overlapping instead of being clustered in a circular format/more concentric. I used the code in the question above.

I'm getting the following output:
[image]
I'm guessing it has to do with the spacing of the nodes that is causing them to overlap and not create a circular cluster.

I want the nodes to look like this, like in the solution for the above question:
[image]

Comment: In the linked solution, they use the variable `rad` (set to 13) when defining the `repos` values to set the radii of the nodes. You may have to play around with that value to get your clusters to have a wider radius.

Comment: @cookesd I've tried all values possible for `rad`, the nodes still end up overlapping.